# How to handle unix.timestamp decoding in an mqtt.client loop over continues messages

Tags: python, mqtt, unix-timestamp, decoding

I am conncecting to an mqtt broker in my python code which sends me a json objects with

{value:7504, timestamp:1562595566}

I would like to decode the timestamp and send then the value via http post or another mqtt client to another server. So it is basically stream forwarding.

So before I start to send it to the server I just wanted to print the decoded value first. Which should be possible since I receive the messages every 10 s only. However as soon as I put in the decoding (print(datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_time_from_json_object))) i will not be able to print the payload anymore. No exceptions are called. So I put the decoding in a function and thought that threading might help here. But this doesn't work either. I am running out of ideas.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Author: 
# Company: 
#
# Program: 
#
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Module
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
from threading import Thread
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Thread


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Variablen
mqtt_broker = "broker_address"
client_id = "some_client_id"
client_user_id = "client_user_id"
client_pw = "some_password"
server = "http://{ip_adress}/"
topic = "topic/1/topic/#"

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Functions

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    # Manual subscription to the topics of the charging stations on the sensor things server
    #for x in range(54, 758):
    #    client.subscribe("v1.0/Datastreams(" + str(x) + ")/Observations")
    client.subscribe(topic)


def time_decode(unix_time):
    utc = datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_time)
    return utc


# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    # print(msg.topic +" "+str(msg.payload))
    payload = json.loads(msg.payload)
    utc = payload['timestamp']
    print(time_decode(utc))
    print(payload)
    #threading.Thread(target=time_decode, args=(utc)).start()
    #t = Thread(target=time_decode, args=(payload['timestamp'])
    #t.start()

    #print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(payload['timestamp']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main program

client = mqtt.Client()
client.username_pw_set(client_user_id, client_pw)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

# client.connect("ip_adress", 1883, 60)
client.connect(mqtt_broker, 1883, 60)
client.loop_forever()
#thread2 = Thread(target=client.loop_forever)


#thread2.start()
```

So what I would like have in a first place is to print the decoded time everytime I receive a message. Secondly I want to build a new json object with the value and date-timestamp and send this via http post or mqtt to another server

Answer (score 0):

Add a try/except block round the call to time_decode to catch and print the error. The on_message function is called inside it's own try/except that throws away any errors, so you will not see any exceptions thrown with in it normally.

Something like:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
  # print(msg.topic +" "+str(msg.payload))
  payload = json.loads(msg.payload)
  utc = payload['timestamp']
  try:
    print(time_decode(utc))
  except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
  print(payload)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. After adding the try/except, the script just prints the connection result and after that nothing is happening, no exceptions messages. I have the impression that some process is waiting vor something.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for the problem. The code itself is right.

I edited the code as

```
try:
    print(time_decode(utc))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print(e.args)
print(payload)
```

this resulted in an error message (ivalid argument). Thus it turned out that the unix timestamp was provided as integer including the ms. Hence I just needed to devide the value by 1000.

Comment: So my answer was right, just the syntax to grab the exception details were a little out...